# running bash pipe commands in background with & ampersand

Tags: bash, shell

```
time for i in `ls /tmp/chunk*`; do (cat $i | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq > /tmp/line${i:10}) & ;done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Whats the syntax error in the above command? I also tried using `{}` and ended the piped commands with `;`. But same error shows up ...

Comment: The difference between the answers below is that `{}` is executed in the current shell context. The `()` creates a new subshell, so you don't retain the variable assignments.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should put the `&` inside the `()`, if you want to run all the jobs in parallel in the background.

```
time for i in `ls /tmp/chunk*`; do
  (cat $i | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq > /tmp/line${i:10} &)
done
```

Comment: This is because & and ; are both command separators: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034909/why-do-i-get-unexpected-token]

Comment: How to get pid of the last command in this format? This will not work: "uniq_pid=$!"

Answer (score 30):

You can include the & in braces:

```
time for i in `ls /tmp/chunk*`; do
  {(cat $i | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq > /tmp/line${i:10}) &};
done
```

Comment: Thanks @IcanDivideBy0 ... but one can only accept one answer. Nice nick BTW :D

Comment: @Tathagata: you can upvote this answer to give the poster 10 rep.

Comment: For those interested the difference between `()` and `{}` is explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/606435/139735). In short: `()` starts a subshell with a new context, `{}` doesn't spawn a new subshell and keeps the parent scope. Note that with `()` variables from the parent scope ARE carried over - hence why the above works.

Answer (score 14):

& is a separator and so is redundant with ;
I.E. remove the final ;

```
for i in /tmp/chunk*; do tr ' ' '\n' <$i | sort -u > /tmp/line${i:10}& done
```