# Why do I get "unexpected token `;'?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to run a few instances of my `bash` script `foo.bash` in background.

When I write `for i in {1..10}; do ~/bin/foo.bash & ; done` in the command line I get an error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ;`

Could you explain why this error occurs and how to fix the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&` and `;` are both command separators; you don't need (and can't have) both.

```
for i in {1..10}; do ~/bin/foo.bash & done
```